# How to show vectors span a set?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Say if I have $V=${$(1,0,1),(0,0,1),(0,1,0)$} , how can I show that $V$ spans $\mathbb R^3$?

I believe there is a theorem that if the dimension of the vector space is $n$, then $n$ linearly independent vectors span the vector space, so I only need to show the vectors are linearly independent, since $\mathbb R^3$ is a vector space of dimension $3$ over $\mathbb R$?

Say if I wanted to prove it without this theorem, what would I do ? Would I need to show that a generic vector $(a,b,c)$ can be formed from any linear combination of the vectors in $V$? As in, would I need to find the coordinate vector of $(a,b,c)$?

I believe in this case I can write $(a,b,c) = (\alpha, \gamma,\alpha + \beta)$, so we have $(a,b,c) = a(1,0,1)+(c-a)(0,0,1)+b(0,1,0)$. This means $V$ spans $\mathbb R^3$ since every vector can be obtained by taking a linear combination of these vectors in $V$????

Comment: Did you mean $b(0,\color{blue}1,\color{blue}0)$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes

Comment: Yes. Both of those solutions are perfectly fine.

Comment: You just have to pick an arbitrary vector $(a,b,c)$ and see if you can get it with a linear combination of the three vectors. This resukts in solving a linear system that you can easily solve.

Comment: Yes. your solution is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the rank of the matrix formed by each vector in $V$. So, $$rank \left(\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0  \end{bmatrix}\right)= 3 $$ So $V$ spans $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: That's the same as checking linear independence.